# expressjs external request memory leak

Tags: node.js, express, request

I am following this pattern for all my express js requests
1- get current user info
2- talk to an external API 
3- return response from external API

now I am not sure why this pattern is causing some serious memory leaks

I am using [npm request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) for all my external requests:

```
exports.createItem = function (req, res) {
    auth.getUserInfo(req, function(user){
        if(!user){
            return res.sendStatus(401)
        }

        request.post(config.externalServiceUrl + '/create', { json: {
            itemId: req.fields.itemId
        } }, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.sendStatus(500);
            } else {
                res.sendStatus(httpResponse.statusCode);
            }
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me. I think I'd try hooking in the Chrome dev tools and taking some heap snapshots.

Comment: What does `auth.getUserInfo()` do?  There's nothing in the code you show that would cause memory leaks unless some of these async calls are taking forever to call their callbacks (thus keeping the `res` and `req` objects alive for a very long time).

Comment: auth.UserInfo() also calls another external API to get user info from a given token

Comment: further debugging shows=> "Can't set headers after they are sent" 
and sometimes shows the popular set max listeners error (memory leak)